# Rendering HTML webpage with restful flask - Webpage not displaying properly

Tags: python, html, flask-restful

I am trying to render an HTML page on local host with restful flask api. The content of HTML page gets displayed as string with "" rather than the page.

```
class data(Resource):
    def get(self):
        #return "Welcome!"
        return render_template('index.html')


api.add_resource(data,'/')
```

My index.html file contains the following content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the site!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

After running the code, on the webpage(http://localhost:5000/) I get the following content

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Welcome to the Data Hosting Service</h1>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

On the other hand,It is returning the text "Welcome!" normally. Can you help me ?

Update:
With the help from users, I have fixed this problem by changing the response type as follows,

```
from flask import Response, render_template
return Response(render_template('index.html'),mimetype='text/html')
```

Comment: That's probably because you are inheriting from `Resource`. RESTful API's usually return JSON strings not rendered HTML content.

Comment: can you tell the content type of response. may be flask-Restful changes th default from text/html to text or json.

Comment: How am I supposed to fix this ?

Comment: The type is unicode

Answer (score 2):

You may need import `make_repsone` from `flask` to render your html with headers information.

```
from flask import make_response, render_template
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
return make_response(render_template('index.html'),200,headers)
```

Hope this could be helpful.